# Cocoa application Enter Full Screen no keyboard shortcut shown

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have a Cocoa application. In the View menu, the system adds an Enter Full Screen menu item. In other applications I see that this menu item has the keyboard shortcut ^⌘F. However in my application this keyboard shortcut is not shown in the menu and unsurprisingly this key combination does not enter full screen.

Interestingly, this keyboard shortcut, although shown in other applications, does not work.

How do I debug and/or fix this?

Comment: Take a look at the View menu in a new Xcode macOS Cocoa App project.

Comment: Yes I did that, and it is there. Definitely something in my app, though don't know what at this point. I can create a new app and migrate my code over until it breaks, but if anyone has some insight as to possible causes that might make things quicker.

Comment: Is the Enter Full Screen menu item present in the View menu in the xib/storyboard?

Comment: No, it gets added to the end at runtime it seems.

Comment: Add (copy, paste) the menu item in the xib/storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Any new Xcode application should get the `View` menu with `Enter Full Screen` already setup. 
You can add the Key command in the Attributes Inspector.

[image]

If the key command doesn't work in ANY application, then that's likely a non-programming problem: most likely a conflict with a duplicate key command that's been configured.

Check System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts.